# How to extract common elements from two 2D array using Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working on to extract common elements/values from a two 2D arrays using python script. I know we can extract common elements in two lists.

Example:

Here, a and b are two 2D arrays:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]...]
b = [[7,8],[1,2],[87,65],[3,4]...]
```

and output should be an another 2D array:

```
c = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: `list(set(map(tuple, a)).intersection(map(tuple, b)))`

Comment: `{frozenset(e) for e in a} & {frozenset(e) for e in b}`

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse `a` list and use the `in` operator to check if the selected element is on `b`:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
b = [[7,8],[1,2],[87,65],[3,4]]

l = [i for i in a if i in b]
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Same goes for checking if element in b is in a

Answer (score 0):

Convert the lists of lists to sets of tuples, then find their intersection:

```
def tuple_set(seq):
    return {tuple(item) for item in seq}

print(tuple_set(a) & tuple_set(b))
```

If needed, convert the result back to a list of lists:

```
print([list(item) for item in tuple_set(a) & tuple_set(b)])
```